# Spring MVC and java script(addRows function) binding

Tags: spring-mvc, javascript-framework

I have question/issue with javascript function binding in Spring MVC . As per our requirement I need to insert a NEW ROW in a table when the user clicks on “ADD” button .

Step1 : So when the user clicks on “Add MORE” button I inserting a new row within a table , I am handling this using javascript

Step 2: When user clicks on the submit button ,  I Need to send the values entered by user to my Controller (Spring MVC Controller) .

So how can binding the values to controller dynamically ?

Please help me to resolve this issue ASAP .

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if you provide examples of your table HTML, JavaScript and controller code.

Answer (score 0):

I do the following when I need to bind a dynamic list of objects coming from the front end :

Post the data as a `json array`, i.e. in the following format

{ data : [{a:1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}] }

In the `Controller`

```
@RequestMapping(value="save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void save(JSONObject object)
{
 List<YourType> list = new ArrayList<YourType>();
 JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("data")
 for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++)
 {
   //getObjectFromJson is your method for converting json to an object of your type.
   list.add(JsonUtils.fromJson(array.getJSONObject(i).toString(), YourType.class);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring can bind maps and lists of objects if you give create an appropriate class to hold your form data then use the `@ModelAttribute` annotation on your controller method.

For example, if your JavaScript creates table rows like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="bells[0]" /></td>
    <td><input name="whistles[0]" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="bells[1]" /></td>
    <td><input name="whistles[1]" /></td>
</tr>
```

Then you can create a model class that contains a list for each repeating field in your HTML form, like this:

```
public class AsapForm {
    private List<String> bells;
    private List<String> whistles;

    // add getters and setters here
}
```

And then you can create a controller method that uses that class as a parameter with the `@ModelAttribute` annotation:

```
public void postAsapForm(@ModelAttribute("contactForm") AsapForm asapForm, BindingResult result) {
    ...
}
```

You can then access the values for each row using `asapForm.getBells()` and `asapForm.getWhistles()` etc.

Comment: This will not bind the dynamically added row. You have to initialize the list with a specific number of size.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using **LazyList**.

You need to do this in following way.

**Operation.java**

```
    package com.xxx.xxx.model;
// Generated Feb 9, 2012 11:30:06 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.apache.commons.collections.FactoryUtils;
import org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList;

@Entity
@Table(name="Operations"
    ,schema="dbo"

)
public class Operations  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int operationId;
     @Embedded
     private Services services;
     private String operationName;
     private String isHqlsql;
     private String isMultipleTables;
     private String listOfTablesAffected;
     private String hqlQuery;
     private String typeOfOperation;
     private String operationDetail;
     private String inputVariables;
     private String outputparamdatatype;
     private String isCountQuery;
     private String isDynamicWhereQry;
     private String isPaginationRequired;
     private String biInputParameters;
    private List<OperationParameters> operationParameterses = LazyList
            .decorate(new ArrayList<OperationParameters>(),
                    FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(OperationParameters.class));

    public Operations() {
    }


    public Operations(int operationId, Services services, String operationName) {
        this.operationId = operationId;
        this.services = services;
        this.operationName = operationName;
    }
    public Operations(int operationId, Services services, String operationName, String isHqlsql, String isMultipleTables, String listOfTablesAffected, String hqlQuery, String typeOfOperation, String operationDetail, String inputVariables, String outputparamdatatype, String isCountQuery, List operationParameterses) {
       this.operationId = operationId;
       this.services = services;
       this.operationName = operationName;
       this.isHqlsql = isHqlsql;
       this.isMultipleTables = isMultipleTables;
       this.listOfTablesAffected = listOfTablesAffected;
       this.hqlQuery = hqlQuery;
       this.typeOfOperation = typeOfOperation;
       this.operationDetail = operationDetail;
       this.inputVariables = inputVariables;
       this.outputparamdatatype = outputparamdatatype;
       this.isCountQuery = isCountQuery;
       this.operationParameterses = operationParameterses;
    }

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="operationId", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public int getOperationId() {
        return this.operationId;
    }

    public void setOperationId(int operationId) {
        this.operationId = operationId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="serviceId", nullable=false)
    public Services getServices() {
        return this.services;
    }

    public void setServices(Services services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

    @Column(name="operationName", nullable=false, length=250)
    public String getOperationName() {
        return this.operationName;
    }

    public void setOperationName(String operationName) {
        this.operationName = operationName;
    }

    @Column(name="isHQLSQL", length=50)
    public String getIsHqlsql() {
        return this.isHqlsql;
    }

    public void setIsHqlsql(String isHqlsql) {
        this.isHqlsql = isHqlsql;
    }

    @Column(name="isMultipleTables", length=50)
    public String getIsMultipleTables() {
        return this.isMultipleTables;
    }

    public void setIsMultipleTables(String isMultipleTables) {
        this.isMultipleTables = isMultipleTables;
    }

    @Column(name="listOfTablesAffected", length=500)
    public String getListOfTablesAffected() {
        return this.listOfTablesAffected;
    }

    public void setListOfTablesAffected(String listOfTablesAffected) {
        this.listOfTablesAffected = listOfTablesAffected;
    }

    @Column(name="hqlQuery")
    public String getHqlQuery() {
        return this.hqlQuery;
    }

    public void setHqlQuery(String hqlQuery) {
        this.hqlQuery = hqlQuery;
    }

    @Column(name="typeOfOperation", length=50)
    public String getTypeOfOperation() {
        return this.typeOfOperation;
    }

    public void setTypeOfOperation(String typeOfOperation) {
        this.typeOfOperation = typeOfOperation;
    }

    @Column(name="operationDetail")
    public String getOperationDetail() {
        return this.operationDetail;
    }

    public void setOperationDetail(String operationDetail) {
        this.operationDetail = operationDetail;
    }

    @Column(name="inputVariables", length=5000)
    public String getInputVariables() {
        return this.inputVariables;
    }

    public void setInputVariables(String inputVariables) {
        this.inputVariables = inputVariables;
    }

    @Column(name="outputparamdatatype", length=50)
    public String getOutputparamdatatype() {
        return this.outputparamdatatype;
    }

    public void setOutputparamdatatype(String outputparamdatatype) {
        this.outputparamdatatype = outputparamdatatype;
    }

    @Column(name="isCountQuery", length=10)
    public String getIsCountQuery() {
        return this.isCountQuery;
    }

    public void setIsCountQuery(String isCountQuery) {
        this.isCountQuery = isCountQuery;
    }

    public String getIsDynamicWhereQry() {
        return isDynamicWhereQry;
    }


    public void setIsDynamicWhereQry(String isDynamicWhereQry) {
        this.isDynamicWhereQry = isDynamicWhereQry;
    }


    public String getIsPaginationRequired() {
        return isPaginationRequired;
    }


    public void setIsPaginationRequired(String isPaginationRequired) {
        this.isPaginationRequired = isPaginationRequired;
    }

    public String getBiInputParameters() {
        return biInputParameters;
    }


    public void setBiInputParameters(String biInputParameters) {
        this.biInputParameters = biInputParameters;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="operations")
    public List<OperationParameters> getOperationParameterses() {
        return this.operationParameterses;
    }

    public void setOperationParameterses(List<OperationParameters> operationParameterses) {
        this.operationParameterses = operationParameterses;
    }

}
```

**OperationParameters.java**

```
package com.xxx.xxx.model;

// Generated Feb 9, 2012 11:30:06 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="OperationParameters"
    ,schema="dbo"

)
public class OperationParameters  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int parameterId;
     private Operations operations;
     private String inputOutputParamName;
     private String inputOutputParamType;
     private String inputOutputParamDataType;

    public OperationParameters() {
    }

    public OperationParameters(int parameterId, Operations operations, String inputOutputParamName, String inputOutputParamType, String inputOutputParamDataType) {
       this.parameterId = parameterId;
       this.operations = operations;
       this.inputOutputParamName = inputOutputParamName;
       this.inputOutputParamType = inputOutputParamType;
       this.inputOutputParamDataType = inputOutputParamDataType;
    }

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="parameterId", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public int getParameterId() {
        return this.parameterId;
    }

    public void setParameterId(int parameterId) {
        this.parameterId = parameterId;
    }
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="operationId", nullable=false)
    public Operations getOperations() {
        return this.operations;
    }

    public void setOperations(Operations operations) {
        this.operations = operations;
    }

    @Column(name="inputOutputParamName", nullable=false, length=250)
    public String getInputOutputParamName() {
        return this.inputOutputParamName;
    }

    public void setInputOutputParamName(String inputOutputParamName) {
        this.inputOutputParamName = inputOutputParamName;
    }

    @Column(name="inputOutputParamType", nullable=false, length=250)
    public String getInputOutputParamType() {
        return this.inputOutputParamType;
    }

    public void setInputOutputParamType(String inputOutputParamType) {
        this.inputOutputParamType = inputOutputParamType;
    }

    @Column(name="inputOutputParamDataType", nullable=false, length=250)
    public String getInputOutputParamDataType() {
        return this.inputOutputParamDataType;
    }

    public void setInputOutputParamDataType(String inputOutputParamDataType) {
        this.inputOutputParamDataType = inputOutputParamDataType;
    }




}
```

**Conroller method to serve the post request to add new Operation.**

```
/**
     * Method that will serve the post request to add the operation and operation parameters submitted by the user.
     * @param operations
     * @param map
     * @return {@link String} The view name that will redirect to the get request to display the previous page with newly entered operation in the list. 
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addOperations(@ModelAttribute Operations operations, ModelMap map) {
        operations.getOperationParameterses().removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

        for(int i=0; i<operations.getOperationParameterses().size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("parameterName :: " + ((OperationParameters)operations.getOperationParameterses().get(i)).getInputOutputParamName());
            if(((OperationParameters)operations.getOperationParameterses().get(i)).getInputOutputParamName() == null || "".equalsIgnoreCase((((OperationParameters)operations.getOperationParameterses().get(i))).getInputOutputParamName())) {
                operations.getOperationParameterses().remove(i);
                System.out.println("empty parameter removed....");
            }
        }

        return "redirect:/operations/" + operations.getServices().getServiceId();
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: One JSP page how you are adding the dynamic row?